# Knockout: ring-fencing observables in a single property

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

My knockout view-model is becoming rather large and I have several observable functions and event handlers relating to a property `BillingAddress`.

For example, I have

```
self.BillingAddressEdit
self.BillingAddressEditMode
self.BillingAddressAddNew
self.BillingAddressAddNewMode
self.BillingAddresses
self.BillingAddressesLoading
```

...and several others.

What I'd like to do is gather these into a BillingAddress object (or function?) which has those same observables as properties.

So something effectively like this

```
self.BillingAddress = {    // or possibly function() {
    AddNew: ko.observable(),
    AddNewMode: ko.observable(),
    Addresses: ko.observableArray(),
    Edit: ko.observable(),
    EditMode: ko.observable(),
    Loading: ko.observable()
}
```

And access these on the view like so

```
<tagName data-bind="foreach: BillingAddress.Addresses">
</tagName>
```

To achieve this, what form would this `BillingAddress` object or function take inside my existing view-model?

Comment: This example on the knockout site might be useful: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html and here's the related JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/GSvnh/ that you can fork and modify to changes names and children to BillingAddress and Addresses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `BillingAddress` can be a single object. The function is userful when your child view model used multiple times, for example in `observableArray` in root model.

**Update:**

`self` variable is used to remember context of viewModel. It is userful when you have some callbacks, which can have own context.

In your case your models can looks like this:

```
var BillingAddressViewModel = {
    AddNew: ko.observable(),
    AddNewMode: ko.observable(),
    Addresses: ko.observableArray(),
    Edit: ko.observable(),
    EditMode: ko.observable(),
    Loading: ko.observable()
}

function RootViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.BillingAddress = BillingAddressViewModel;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how this would be written out? For example, does my example in the question have it correct? Should there be `self.` prefixing each property?

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a go and report back as soon as I can.

Comment: Yes, works perfectly. Not sure what I had done wrongly in the example I gave, but it's working now. Thanks @Alexander.